# Oracle SQL: How to add a col to assign a seq no. but only 1 and 2 (per unique id)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, analytics

Is there a way to assign a value ("IdNo") sequentially, 1 and 2, per CustNo? Below is my query (or I can put this query in a view), but not sure how to add an "IdNo" column that will just assign a "1" and "2" respectively, per unique CustNo.

```
 with row as
(select z.*,
        row_number ()
            over (partition by CustNo
                  order by FoodDate desc)    rn
   from table z)
  select CustNo,
         Food,
         FoodDate   
    from row
   where rn <= 2
order by CustNo, FoodDate desc
```

Below is what I want it to look like with the IdNo added...

```
IdNo    CustNo    Food                FoodDate
1       101       Red-Apple           7/5/22
2       101       Red-Apple           7/5/22
1       256       Red-Apple           7/11/22
2       256       Red-Cherry          5/20/22
1       418       Blue-Muffin         4/1/22 
2       418       Blue-Berry          3/16/22
1       599       Orange-Persimmon    2/8/22
2       599       Red-Apple           1/23/22
1       654       Blue-Berry          12/4/21
2       654       Yellow-Banana       11/27/21
```

Comment: How about adding rn on your query? `select rn as IdNo, CustNo,.....`

Comment: @EdBangga exactly what I wanted!! Please post your answer so I can select it as correct, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add **rn** on your query.

```
with row as
(select z.*,
        row_number ()
            over (partition by CustNo
                  order by FoodDate desc)    rn
   from table z)
  select rn as IdNo,
         CustNo,
         Food,
         FoodDate   
    from row
   where rn <= 2
order by CustNo, FoodDate desc
```